# Passing URL variables to AS2, is it possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, url-parameters

I'm trying to load a swf file into another one (both AS2.0). Here is the code for the main .fla file (let's say main.fla):

```
loadMovie("http://.../file.swf?myId=" + my_id, myMovieclip);
```

And here is how file.fla looks like:

```
trace('_root.loaderInfo.parameters.myId:' + _root.loaderInfo.parameters.myId);
trace('_level0.myId:' + _level0.myId);
```

And the result is:

```
_root.loaderInfo.parameters.myId:undefined
_level0.myId:undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? As you can see, this should work with no html file (so I can't use FlashVars).

Answer (score 0):

When you load a SWF into a parent in ActionScript 2.0, any calls to `_root` and (I think) `_level0` from the child SWF will refer to properties on the parent. The simplest workaround for this is to use the `_lockroot` property (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001321.html)) which, when set to true in the child SWF, will ensure that any references to `_root` refer to it rather than the parent.

So try adding the following on to your child SWF:

```
this._lockroot = true;
```